# Issues with Excel SUMIF INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, excel-2010, sumifs

I'm working on an Excel 2010 sheet using a series of tables to calculate a variable sum. See the below image for what I'm working with.

Encounter Calculations:

[image]

Table 1 `Table_Encounters`. The column `XP Limit` is supposed to look at the current value in `Difficulty`, match appropriate column in Table 2 `Table_Players`, then add together all numbers in that specific column.

For example, in `G3`, it should be referencing `F3` (Hard), finding Table_Players[Hard], and adding together `O3:O10`, displaying a result of `8000 (1100+1100+1100+1100+1100+1400+1100)`.

Every combination of `sumif`, `index`, and `match` I try either returns `0`, `#ref`, or `#value`. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, and have been scratching my head over this for the last few hours. I thought I was going to the right direction with this, but I only get `#REF` so I'm at a loss:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX([Difficulty],,MATCH(F$3,Table_Players[#Headers],0)),[Difficulty],$F4)
```

Comment: stop trying combinations.  Start with `match`, get that working, and go from there.

Comment: If you limit the range on one you need to limit the range on the criteria also.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I keep noticing that you have a knack for decoding balderdash.  Impressive.

Comment: @ashleedawg Just know the usual suspects.

Comment: @still qualifies as a knack :)

Comment: So backing up to the match, I've had moderate success getting that to work. The below returns the correct column 

> =MATCH([Difficulty],Table_Players[[#Headers],[Player]:[None]],0)

However going from here, I can't get the index to work. It seems to just pick miscellaneous values.

> =INDEX(F$3,MATCH([Difficulty],Table_Players[[#Headers],[Players]:[None]],0))

Just returns #ref. I tried instead using [Difficulty] instead of F$3, and that returns column names but none of them match anything. Sorry in advance for bad comment formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in G3:

```
=SUM(INDEX($K$3:$Q$10,0,MATCH($F3,$K$2:$Q$2,0)))
```

Or with your structured references:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Table_Players[#Data],0,MATCH($F3,Table_Players[#Headers],0)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to come back with the latter solution. One day I'll get the hang of all this

Comment: If this worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.